# When I pase data from one workbook to a table in another workbook the rows do not auto expand

Tags: vba, excel

When I paste data from one workbook to a table in another work book the rows do not auto expand. I have included the code I am running in case there is something I am missing.

```
Dim MyPath$, MyWB$

MyPath = "C:\Documents\"

MyWB = "Rec.xlsm"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

 ChDir MyPath
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "C:\Documents\FQC.xlsx"

    ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(2)(1, 1).Select

    Range(ActiveCell.Address, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Copy

    Workbooks(MyWB).Sheets("Finance QC Report Table").ListObjects("Table111").DataBodyRange.PasteSpecial

    Workbooks("FQC.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Comment: Please elaborate on the expected result.

Comment: Hi Ralph,  basically what I am trying to do is copy the data from the "FQC" workbook into Table111 that is in the  "Finance QC Report Table" worksheet in MyWB. Currently, when the data gets pasted into Table111 the rows do not auto expand so I have to manually drag down to the last row

Comment: How many rows are you copying from ActiveSheet, and how many rows are there in Table111?

Comment: The rows in ActiveSheet changes on a weekly basis so that is why I'm running into the problem.  One week I might have to input 100 rows and the following week I might have to input 150 rows.